# how to writhe a Php inside HTML with substr

Tags: php

I write this bellow code

```
<div class="description"><?php echo substr($data['description'],strpos($data['description'],$info['title']),100); ?></div>
```

when I change method to this bellow code I get an error!!

```
 <?php echo'<div class="description">'.substr('.$data['description'].',strpos('.$data['description'].','.$info['title']).',100).'</div>'; ?>
```

> error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING...

Comment: Parse error: syntax error ........

Comment: Where is your `php tag` ???

Comment: @Saty I have written php tag at the top of the Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write your PHP code inside `<?php` and `?>` tags.

You cant just write your php code as a string. PHP interpreter needs to know what code should be interpreted.

EDIT:

You cant put variables names in quotes. Try this:

```
<?php echo '<div class="description">' . substr($data['description'], strpos($data['description'], $info['title']), 100) . '</div>'; ?>
```

Comment: I have written php tag at the top of the The second Code

Comment: thank you very much. It worked:)